# How to run j2me game in browser

Tags: java-me

I have some j2me games, usually running in "KEmulator", and I want to publish them on my server and play them using a browser, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If source code of the j2me file ( .jar ) is available , the game can be compiled to run in browser.

Comment: Yes, the source code is available. I just don't know which approach is better to use. I've tried the "pluotsorbet" project before, but it didn't build successfully.